# Close all other sub-menus on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, drop-down-menu

**Hello everyone,**
Thank you for taking the time to view this post.

I have the following problem I am trying to create a menu with sub-menus.

Menu should:

1. Open sub-menus on click. (working)
2. Sub-menus stay open on selected menu. (working)

   **3. Once clicked in other menus the previous sub-menus should close. (not working)**

HTML

```
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <ul class="bottom-menu">
      <li class="drop"><a>Hyperlink 1</a></li>
      <li class="drop"><a>Hyperlink 2</a>
      <ul id="m1" class="bottom-menu-sub">
        <li><a href="#">Hyperlink Sub</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Hyperlink Sub</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Hyperlink Sub</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="drop"><a>Hyperlink 3</a>
      <ul id="m2">
        <li><a href="#">Hyperlink Sub</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Hyperlink Sub</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="drop"><a>Hyperlink 4</a>
      <ul id="m3">
        <li><a href="#">Hyperlink Sub</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Hyperlink Sub</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
      .bottom-menu li ul {
      display:none;
      }
```

JS:

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    // jQuery code in here can safely use $
    $('.bottom-menu li')
        .css({
        cursor: "pointer"
    });

    $(".drop>a").on('click', function (eventData) {
        var $listItem = $(this).closest('li');

        $listItem.find('ul').toggle();
        $listItem.toggleClass('open');

        $.cookie('open_items', 'the_value');
        openItems = new Array();
        $("li.drop").each(function (index, item) {
            if ($(item).hasClass('open')) {
                openItems.push(index);
            }
        });
        $.cookie('open_items', openItems.join(','));
    });

    if ($.cookie('open_items') && $.cookie('open_items').length > 0) {
        previouslyOpenItems = $.cookie('open_items');
        openItemIndexes = previouslyOpenItems.split(',');
        $(openItemIndexes).each(function (index, item) {
            $("li.drop").eq(item).addClass('open').find('ul').toggle();
        });
    }
});
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rb2wxurL/)

Comment: what they usually do is close everything as soon as your `click` event fires.

Comment: Just wonder, Why do you use cookies for simple dropdown menu?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add This Line `$(".bottom-menu li").removeClass('open');`

add this css

```
.bottom-menu li ul {
    display:none;
}
.bottom-menu li.open ul{
  display:block;
}




jQuery(function ($) {
        // jQuery code in here can safely use $
        $('.bottom-menu li')
            .css({
            cursor: "pointer"
        });

        $(".drop>a").on('click', function (eventData) {
        $(".bottom-menu li").removeClass('open');// Add This Line
            var $listItem = $(this).closest('li');


            $listItem.toggleClass('open');

            $.cookie('open_items', 'the_value');
            openItems = new Array();
            $("li.drop").each(function (index, item) {
                if ($(item).hasClass('open')) {
                    openItems.push(index);
                }
            });
            $.cookie('open_items', openItems.join(','));
        });

        if ($.cookie('open_items') && $.cookie('open_items').length > 0) {
            previouslyOpenItems = $.cookie('open_items');
            openItemIndexes = previouslyOpenItems.split(',');
            $(openItemIndexes).each(function (index, item) {
                $("li.drop").eq(item).addClass('open');
            });
        }
    });
```

https://jsfiddle.net/rb2wxurL/2/

Answer (score 0):

As Flame already mentioned, what you want to do is close (hide) everything upon click

Edited your snipped by adding

```
            $('.bottom-menu ul').each(function() { 
                $(this).hide();
            });
```

after your click event (takes bottom-menu class, finds each unordered list inside and hides it)

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/WXZaNe

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps you.

```js
jQuery(function ($) {
    // jQuery code in here can safely use $

    $(".drop>a").on('click', function (eventData) {
        var $listItem = $(this).closest('li');
    $('.drop ul').hide();
        $listItem.find('ul').toggle();
        $listItem.toggleClass('open');
        
        //$.cookie('open_items', 'the_value');
        openItems = new Array();
        $("li.drop").each(function (index, item) {
            if ($(item).hasClass('open')) {
                openItems.push(index);
            }
        });
        //$.cookie('open_items', openItems.join(','));
    });

    //if ($.cookie('open_items') && $.cookie('open_items').length > 0) {
    //    previouslyOpenItems = $.cookie('open_items');
    //    openItemIndexes = previouslyOpenItems.split(',');
    //    $(openItemIndexes).each(function (index, item) {
    //        $("li.drop").eq(item).addClass('open').find('ul').toggle();
    //   });
    //}
});
```

```css
.bottom-menu li ul {
    display:none;
}
.bottom-menu li{
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="bottom-menu">
    <li class="drop"><a>Hyperlink 1</a></li>
    <li class="drop"><a>Hyperlink 2</a>
      <ul id="m1" class="bottom-menu-sub">
        <li><a href="#">Hyperlink Sub</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Hyperlink Sub</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Hyperlink Sub</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="drop"><a>Hyperlink 3</a>
      <ul id="m2">
        <li><a href="#">Hyperlink Sub</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Hyperlink Sub</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="drop"><a>Hyperlink 4</a>
      <ul id="m3">
        <li><a href="#">Hyperlink Sub</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Hyperlink Sub</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
</ul>


<p>If you open the "Hyperlink 2", the sub menu will show (that's as entended),</br> Althought once you click "Hyperlink 3" the sub-menus of "Hyperlink 2" stay open.
</p>
```